# Have any governments proposed relaxing drug/vaccine development requirements for the duration of the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: government, covid-19, drugs, regulation, public-health

Given that a vaccine or an effective treatment for COVID-19 is the best way out of the current crisis, it seems logical that governments would take a "no holds barred" approach to making it happen as soon as possible. Have any countries so far announced that they would abolish (or significantly relax) restrictions on drug/vaccine development for the duration of the pandemic?

Comment: +1 This  is somewhat broader than what I asked on med SE about a specific proposal: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23096/have-any-regulatory-agencies-announced-they-would-allow-live-covid-19-human-chal And somewhat related q here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52534/have-non-health-government-officials-in-western-countries-besides-the-us-publi

Comment: I do not know about drugs or vaccines, but in Spain the government has relaxed some restrictions to ease business switching to produce medical material: respirators, face masks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**August 2020 Update**

In light of the severe impact of the pandemic, it is probably fair to say that every country is reassessing the approval process for new vaccines to a greater or lesser degree.

According to the WHO, as of 13th of August 2020, [six](https://www.who.int/publications/m/item/draft-landscape-of-covid-19-candidate-vaccines) vaccines are in Phase III trials, and 16 are between Phase I-II. Phase III trials are essential because they check for problems such as [Antibody-dependent Enhancement(ADE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibody-dependent_enhancement), which is where a vaccine actually helps viruses infect host cells.

**Phase III trials**.

- The U.S.'s leading candidate is the vaccine from Moderna. President Trump launched [Operation Warp Speed](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/president-donald-j-trump-using-every-available-resource-deliver-safe-effective-vaccine-american-people/) to fast-track the release of vaccine candidates, but regulatory approval from the [F.D.A.](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/basics/test-approve.html) is likely to require proof of [success in Phase III trials](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-vaccine-idUSKCN2592YS). I can't find any evidence to suggest that the F.D.A. has relaxed the normal approval process, but they are likely to come under significant pressure from the Whitehouse to do so.
- The vaccine from the U.K.'s University of Oxford, is probably the front-runner both in terms of human trials and pre-orders. They have already received orders for at least [2 billion](https://www.biopharmadive.com/news/astrazeneca-oxford-coronavirus-vaccine-mexico-argentina/583470/) doses globally. Late-stage testing has commenced in at least [three countries](https://english.jagran.com/india/oxford-vaccine-latest-update-phase-3-trials-underway-know-release-date-india-launch-and-more-10015184), and they are the only candidate vaccine to have published [peer-reviewed results](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(20)31604-4/fulltext). In the UK, the [Medicines and Healthcare products Regulatory Agency](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/medicines-and-healthcare-products-regulatory-agency) is the body that oversees the approval of new vaccines. They have released a set of [guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/mhra-regulatory-flexibilities-resulting-from-coronavirus-covid-19) explaining their approach to regulatory flexibilty in light of the COVID emergency. There are conditions under which vaccines can be fast-tracked for emergency use, but they will still have to prove success in Phase III trials first.
- Four vaccines in China are in Phase III trials, and at least two [Phase I](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(20)31208-3/fulltext), and one [Phase II](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2769612?guestAccessKey=5bc9c9c9-9a9d-4c8f-9cb7-47c2b531b226) reviews have been published. Probably the leading [vaccine candidate](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2020-05/23/c_139080149.htm) was developed by Chen Wei's team at the the Beijing Institute of Biotechnology. Unconfirmed reports have claimed that some of these candidate vaccines are already being tested on [employees](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2020-07-16/coronavirus-update-covid19-australia-miami-second-wave-india/12459578) of the companies involved, and other rumors have suggested that they are available for some employees of state-owned companies and the military. It appears therefore likely that China has potentially extended Phase III trials in a somewhat non-traditional way.

**Notable Phase I-II trials**

- The vaccine developed by the Gamaleya Research Institute has [only announced the completion of Phase I trials](https://www.bmj.com/content/370/bmj.m3205), but President Putin has claimed that he has already inoculated [one of his daughters](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/covid-vaccine-russia-coronavirus-development/). The results of the phase I trials haven't been publically peer reviewed. This suggests a severe relaxation of normal regulations. Indeed, on 14th August, top respiratory doctor Professor Alexander Chuchalin has quit the Russian health ministry, citing [ethics violations](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/health-news/russia-coronavirus-vaccine-russias-top-respiratory-doctor-quits-over-untested-covid-vaccine-calls-it-gross-violations-of-ethics/photostory/77540389.cms) concerning the registration of this new vaccine.

Answer (score 8):

I am totally sure there is a lot of relaxation going on already.  For example, I believe the recent [Seattle-based vaccine trial](https://www.livescience.com/coronavirus-vaccine-trial-no-animal-testing.html) went straight to human volunteers, bypassing the animal testing stage.  Note that this link criticizes that decision - I don't myself, but it's just the first link to this trial I found.

Thing is, and especially with a relatively low mortality disease like covid, you really don't want to make things worse than they by mass-treatment with the wrong approach.  You do need to make sure it does what it supposed to do and that it doesn't hurt.

Here's a [review of vaccine candidates](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41573-020-00073-5), from Nature - at 78, it sounds like things are off to quick start.  Note 1 item in this article: **90+% of vaccine candidates in normal times don't work out, for whatever reason.**  Or, to put things in a different perspective, how many times have you read about *revolutionary cancer treatments* in the last 2-3 decades?  Sure, we are slowly beating cancer - which unlike covid is a bunch of diseases - but by now anyone paying attention knows that just because someone has found something interesting doesn't mean the work is done, no matter how appealing the headlines.

Even if safe, if it doesn't actually help, how are you ever going to convince "vaccinated" folk to observe social distance, if they are "immune"?

Now, I am totally with you that 12-18 months seems like a lot.  Maybe some of it can be shaved off.  But that should be driven by what experts in the field, with a strong mandate to limit red tape **this one time** can do.

Take our friend [hydroxychloroquine](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2020/04/06/hydroxychloroquine-update-for-april-6).  It is not a *safe* drug at any time and needs careful monitoring.  Barging ahead and prescribing it, without showing that it works is something no one should do in this case.  There's nothing wrong with testing hydroxychloroquine, and quickly, but the pros and cons need to assessed before large scale use.  Right now, the pros are starting to look like the limits of doing cutting edge research very quickly, without sufficient time for assessment.  It's not that it was wrong to think it might help, or pursuing accelerated tests, but it might end up being a dead end, using a drug with known serious side effects.

If hydroxychloroquine works, great.  That's what 3-4 weeks of lockdown so far are buying us, the "luxury" of making rational choices and preparing to beat this, using the best experts in the field.  And it's not like that's the only drug being looked at either - if Trump hadn't mouthed off about it, no one would even know it exists.

#### A bad vaccine may be worse than no vaccine

Edit: Since some people that are all gung-ho about full steam ahead, I'll add an extra bit of info re. vaccination risks that is getting mentioned wrt covid.

One of the ways covid seems to kill some people is [overstimulation of the immune system](https://www.forbes.com/sites/claryestes/2020/04/16/what-is-the-cytokine-storm-and-why-is-it-so-deadly-for-covid-19-patients/#6064ff44460f) (this was also the case in the 1918 Flu).  And we know that *some vaccines for some diseases can make this problem worse under some conditions*.  Probably because they've primed the immune system to overreact.  This is the case with [dengue fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengue_vaccine).  Imagine if we broadly vaccinated against covid, just to find out later that a non-negligible proportion of the population did worse because of untested vaccine effects?

Covid is a 1-5% death rate disease, at least when the local health system is not swamped.  It is **not** rabies (100%) or Ebola (60%).  That means we don't have the ethical right, or just the cold mathematical basis cost/benefit basis, to just barge in and hope for the best, based on our gut feelings.

**We can, and should, take some shortcuts, but we have to do it intelligently, based on the knowledge of people who do this for a living.  That doesn't mean we can't ask hard questions however.**

**I wouldn't tell my mechanic how to fix my car, I wonder why so many now claim to know better than vaccination and epidemiology experts.**

Comment: Moderna's Seattle vaccine didn't go far enough in my opinion, as they're not planning to attempt to infect those injected with the vaccine to see if they get sick or not. Otherwise why even bother working on it?

Comment: if batch 1 of size x doesn't get sick then you can "vaccinate" a larger batch 2.  choosing the population carefully, maybe a high risk group for some reason, you'll be able to see if there's a statistical improvement rather quickly.  that's just at a guess, and shows us exactly why we need experts in the field, rather than armchair generals suddenly expert in infectious diseases.

Comment: @JonathanReez: that's not an issue intrinsic to the vaccine itself. Any vaccine can be tested with live challenges... or not. There's another "classical" (not mRNA like Moderna's) vaccine in the works [forgot the comp name], but would take longer to even develop.

Comment: @JonathanReez: the main issue with mRNA vaccines is that the tech is very new and mostly unproven. Also the study participants will be monitored for a full year. https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/nih-clinical-trial-investigational-vaccine-covid-19-begins

Comment: Vaccines are not only about preventing people from getting infected. This is a necessary requirement of course but it is not of great help if your badly tested vaccination makes healthy people sick in other ways. We can safely assume that any working vaccination would be applied to billions of people and even low percentage risks will have a huge impact on that scale

Comment: @JonathanReez: these validation studies proceed in steps. Phase 1 is to check with a small group whether there are no very frequent adverse effects (and in this particular case maybe by blood test whether the desired antibodies are developed). If that works out well, one proceeds to larger studies (e.g. in Germany the regulatory body speaks about hopefully doing validation studies on the scale of 10000 people next year). But it's too risky to immediately subject 1000s of volounteers to to potentially very serious complications. And the Seattle study already skipped the animal tests.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX this is not the time to worry about volunteers safety. As long as people accept the risk of death, it should be okay to do anything to accelerate vaccine development.

Comment: @JonathanReez: you can of course hold this political opinion, but please mark it as such. Personally, I don't hold this opinion: I don't think the potential gains of skipping the phase I trial worth while compared to the additional risk. FYI: I'm told that I have low risk aversion - while I'm not sure, subjectively the risks I take are low. I do agree in general that my society (Germany) lacks a mechanism to monitor efficacy safety regulations and re-evaluate whether they are worth while on a regular and rational basis. But this does not mean that we should allow *panic* to throw safety ...

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I'm talking about people who volunteer to be the first to try out the vaccine, not the general public. If we could instantly know if the vaccine works or not, things would be significantly accelerated

Comment: ... regulations over board. IMHO we (i.e. mostly the ones of us who are professionally trained to do this) need to make as rational as possible a decision which risks are worth while to take now. It doesn't make sense to risk more than can potentially be gained during the time window that skipping one step could possibly give us.

Comment: Skipping phase 1 would not immediately tell us whether the vaccine works or not. But it will deprive us of the possibility to abandon early a candidate that doesn't work out (which is the majority of drug or vaccine candidates, see answer above). Immediately going for 10000 volounteers instead of 50 means also that with 90 % probability we waste the ressources to produce 9950 doses of the vaccine candidate.

Comment: And last but not least, at least where I am we're told to refrain from activities that come at a higher e.g. accident risk in order to not burden the health system. From that perspective the volounteers do not only donate their health (potentially) but if this thing goes wrong (possible while hopefully unlikely), we may also have a  number of additional patients to look after right now (or even worse, to look after long-term).

Comment: Compare this with the possible gains in time we get without any health risk at all (only at the cost of economic ressources) by prioritizing and maybe early preparation of the burocratic requirements of the approval process (which no doubt we *also* do right now).

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX you don't need 10000 volunteers for human challenge testing. 100 young/healthy volunteers, 50 get vaccine, 50 get placebo. After 2 weeks all 100 are infected with COVID-19. Wait for 3 weeks and see what's up. If all 50 in vaccine group are feeling well, pursue the vaccine further. If not, move on.

Answer (score 4):

China has also [fast-tracked](https://www.fiercepharma.com/vaccines/china-s-cansino-pushes-coronavirus-vaccine-into-clinical-testing-as-moderna-doses-1st) their own vaccine development, with testing in humans (news of March 18):

> CanSino Bio and its collaborators at the Academy of Military Medical Sciences’ Institute of Biotechnology secured a quick Chinese regulatory go-ahead to start human testing of their recombinant coronavirus vaccine, the company said in a disclosure (PDF) to the Hong Kong Stock Exchange on Wednesday. [...]
>
> The green light was doled out very quickly. It was only Tuesday when CanSino said it had filed the pre-IND review application for the vaccine to authorities and was in the process of a rolling submission of technical documents. [...]
>
> Meanwhile, amid growing numbers of infections in the U.S., the FDA has allowed a phase 1 study of Moderna’s mRNA vaccine without animal data. On Monday, the biotech said researchers at the National Institutes of Health dosed the first subject. [...]
>
> Besides CanSino and Moderna, many other companies are also working on vaccines for SARS-CoV-2. [...]

I cannot tell you how much "bending of the rules" this is in China, since I'm not familiar with their regulations.  But the timing of the Chinese announcement was roughly two days later after the US announced the first Moderna vaccine dose having been injected into a human (on March 16). Interestingly perhaps, China is [also developing](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/society/article/3075722/china-developing-9-potential-vaccines-global-race-coronavirus) a mRNA vaccine "jointly developed by the Chinese Centre for Disease Control and Prevention, Tongji University and Stermina in Shanghai", but this one is still undergoing animal testing in China, with human testing announced to begin mid-April.

So yeah, the US (NIAID/Moderna) and China (CanSino) are now basically in a "race for the [vaccine] cure". Others will probably join. I suspect they might also benefit from regulatory fast-tracks, possibly depending how well politically connected they are in their test jurisdictions. (The EU has [given](https://www.euronews.com/2020/04/07/covid-19-pandemic-the-race-for-a-vaccine-and-cure-for-the-deadliest-viral-outbreak-in-a-ce) Curevac a grant to work on a mRNA vaccine similar to the Moderna one; however no human tests have begun with that--they've been announced for June. The WHO said that over 40 concrete vaccine candidates have been proposed, with at least a hundred in development.)

The WSJ reported (without a lot of specifics on the regulatory side that):

> Counting drugs approved for other diseases, there are 254 clinical trials testing treatments or vaccines for the virus, many spearheaded by universities and government research agencies, with hundreds more trials planned. Researchers have squeezed timelines that usually total months into weeks or even days.

---

More recent [news (Apr 14)](https://www.rawstory.com/2020/04/the-fda-lets-pretty-much-anyone-sell-a-covid-19-antibody-test-and-a-lot-of-them-are-shoddy-cnn/) regarding Covid-19 anti-bodies tests low standards:

> On CNN Tuesday, senior medical correspondent Elizabeth Cohen warned that many of the antibody tests on the market for COVID-19 — the tests that show whether you are immune to the virus — are barely tested under the Food and Drug Administration’s new standards, and possibly ineffective. [...]
>
> “The problem is, the FDA lowered the standards last month, and basically pretty much anyone can sell an antibody test,” continued Cohen. “They don’t even have to show that it works. All they have to do is say, hey, FDA, I want to sell this test and I validated it here in my city where I am. That’s all they have to do. They don’t have to show their data.”

And after the backlash, there's some sort of review [announced](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/14/health/fda-reverses-antibody-tests/index.html):

> [Scott Becker, CEO of the Association of Public Health Laboratories] said FDA Commissioner Stephen Hahn told him and members of his association that the National Cancer Institute (NCI) would start reviewing tests that are on the market to see if they obtain correct results. [...]
>
> The FDA did not respond to questions for this story, referring CNN to the NCI.

A lot of the media has incorrectly headlined these news as the FDA tightening the (approval) standards, but that doesn't seem to be actually happening yet.

---

And (August edit) to add the [latest story](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/08/13/europe/russia-us-coronavirus-vaccine/index.html) on the Russian vaccine developments:

> Russia enacted a law in April which eliminated the requirement for crucial Phase 3 trials to be conducted before approval. This has allowed researchers to fast-track the vaccine development process.